# SQLSTATE[IM002] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am trying to run some code on my local computer. It's a simple webpage and I am attempting to make a PDO call to the database, but I am getting

```
SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have read a couple of posts and they all point to a possible 32-bit connection or 64-bit connection not being established.
In my ODBC Data Source Administrator I have  both a 64-bit connection and a 32-bit connection under the system DSN, but I am still not able to make any connections. All I get is the error listed above. I'd like to point I am using IIS to run my local webpage. 
I tried creating a user DSN but did not work either. Could this be something with my environment variables?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem?

Comment: I believe my solution was to change the name of the dsn connection from within my php.ini  to the one I had in my ODBC.